# oracle insert and complex select. what's wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i have some complex select and result need to place in the table.
I try this:

```
INSERT INTO SAMGUPS_STATISTIC_STANTION
(SAMGUPS_STATISTIC_STANTION_SEQ.nextval)
(
with PRG as (
select
 ID_OBJ
from PEREGON where ID_STAN1=&arrival
),
STN_OBJ as (
          select
          distinct ID_OBJ_P as ID_OBJ
          from TMO start with ID_OBJ=&dispatch
          connect by prior ID_OBJ_P=ID_OBJ
),
STAN as (
          select
          A_TOP.ID_POEZD
          ,A_TOP.vrsvop
          from STN_OBJ inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=STN_OBJ.ID_OBJ and A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('01','07')
          left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
          WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____'
),
DATA_RESULT as 
(
          select
          /*count(*) over() as TotalCount*/
          to_char(&dispatch) as dispatch
          ,to_char(&arrival) as arrival
          ...
          ,ATR.PR_N_V_PZ
          from PRG inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=PRG.ID_OBJ and  A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('03','07')
                    left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
                    inner join STAN STN on STN.ID_POEZD = ATR.ID_POEZD  
                    WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____'
                    order by A_TOP.ID_POEZD
)
SELECT * FROM DATA_RESULT);
```

i have error:

```
Error at Command Line:71 Column:25
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
32034. 00000 -  "unsupported use of WITH clause"
*Cause:    Inproper use of WITH clause because one of the following two reasons
           1. nesting of WITH clause within WITH clause not supported yet
           2. For a set query, WITH clause can't be specified for a branch.
           3. WITH clause can't sepecified within parentheses.
*Action:   correct query and retry
```

Whether there is to circumvent these restrictions?
May be possible result of select place into variable and then using variable insert to table?

Comment: That isn't even valid for the SQL Server 2005+ code you lifted it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WITH clause can't sepecified within parentheses.

try rewrite smth like this

```
INSERT INTO SAMGUPS_STATISTIC_STANTION
with PRG as (
select
 ID_OBJ
from PEREGON where ID_STAN1=&arrival
),
STN_OBJ as (
          select
          distinct ID_OBJ_P as ID_OBJ
          from TMO start with ID_OBJ=&dispatch
          connect by prior ID_OBJ_P=ID_OBJ
),
STAN as (
          select
          A_TOP.ID_POEZD
          ,A_TOP.vrsvop
          from STN_OBJ inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=STN_OBJ.ID_OBJ and A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('01','07')
          left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
          WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____'
),
DATA_RESULT as 
(
          select
          /*count(*) over() as TotalCount*/
          to_char(&dispatch) as dispatch
          ,to_char(&arrival) as arrival
          ...
          ,ATR.PR_N_V_PZ
          from PRG inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=PRG.ID_OBJ and  A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('03','07')
                    left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
                    inner join STAN STN on STN.ID_POEZD = ATR.ID_POEZD  
                    WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____'
                    order by A_TOP.ID_POEZD
)
SELECT SAMGUPS_STATISTIC_STANTION_SEQ.nextval,  DATA_RESULT.* FROM DATA_RESULT;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. No need for an ORDER BY on an INSERT.
2. An INSERT is coded like this: `INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn, ...) SELECT ...`

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SAMGUPS_STATISTIC_STANTION
(dispatch, arrival, ..., PR_N_V_PZ)
          select
          to_char(&dispatch) as dispatch
          ,to_char(&arrival) as arrival
          ...
          ,ATR.PR_N_V_PZ
          from (select
                 ID_OBJ
                from PEREGON where ID_STAN1=&arrival
                )
          inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=PRG.ID_OBJ and  A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('03','07')
                    left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
                    inner join (select
                                A_TOP.ID_POEZD
                                ,A_TOP.vrsvop
                                from (select
                                      distinct ID_OBJ_P as ID_OBJ
                                      from TMO start with ID_OBJ=&dispatch
                                      connect by prior ID_OBJ_P=ID_OBJ
                                ) inner join A_TOP on A_TOP.ID_OBJ=STN_OBJ.ID_OBJ and A_TOP.KODOP_P in ('01','07')
                                left join A_POEZD_ATR ATR on ATR.ID_POEZD=A_TOP.ID_POEZD and ATR.VRSVOP=A_TOP.VRSVOP
                                WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____') STN
                            on STN.ID_POEZD = ATR.ID_POEZD  
                    WHERE ATR.NOM_POEZD LIKE '____';
```

Comment: In 10g: You cannot specify a query_name in its own subquery. However, any query_name defined in the subquery_factoring_clause can be used in any subsequent named query block in the subquery_factoring_clause.  (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9761)  Although I think CTEs are over-used and something like your way is probably better.